# console.log(this) in global scope returns undefined

Tags: javascript, this

I have created a script which logs the this variable to the console in the global scope. If I launch the script in the browser it returns undefined. eg.

```
console.log(this); //returns undefined
```

However if I enter the same command directly in the browser console it returns the window object. Which is what I was expecting. eg.

`console.log(this); //returns Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}`

Why is the behavior/output of logging 'this' to the console different in the browser console and different while inspecting the output from a script?

**Edit:**
I am compiling the script with babel (es2015 preset).
As far as my initial question is concerned the issue is now resolved.
Disabling the Babel preset/plugins results in the expected output of the this variable.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. If I make a script and then do `console.log(this)` I get the [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object. What browser are you using? Or are you running this from a webworker? or are you running a JavaScript engine like node or nashorn?

Comment: `console.log` always returns undefined

Comment: @Tschallacka I am using the Chrome browser. The script is loaded via an html file with the script tag. I am launching the html file via a prepros live server and inspecting the output in the browser console.

Comment: Is strict mode enabled?

Comment: @OlimSaidov Yes I am beginning to understand, I am guessing since the window object is not returning anything by default, the output will always be undfined for this. But I am still confused about the nature of the output of 'this' directly in the browser console.

Comment: @Sam I'm using chrome too, and I can't reproduce your issue. But you see the output right? `Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}`  What happens if you do `console.log('testing', this);` The console.log() function in itself will never return anything.  It only outputs to console.

Comment: @TiiJ7 You are correct, the strict mode was enabled. I was ignorant to the fact that I am pre processing the script file with Babel, uglify-js and mangle. On inspecting the minified file the script was altered to `"use strict";console.log(void 0);` Which explains the output.

Comment: @Sam If you were using babel, you probably were writing an ES6 module, which doesn't run in global scope and doesn't have any `this`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes i am beginning to understand, The resultant output is due to the babel es2015 preset, As a beginner I am unfamiliar with how babel (and its plugins ) is/are working or the use of the es6 modules. Disabling the babel preset resolved the issues. Thankyou for mentioning this, I will read further into the topic of babel presets and es6 modules.

Comment: @Tschallacka Thankyou very much for your help, I understand now, `console.log('testing', this); //returns testing undefined` .The babel compiler modifies the minified script loaded in the browser to `"use strict";console.log("testing",void 0);` As such explaining why i was receiving undefined as the output. I will read further into the topic of es6 and babel to better understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are using ES6 Modules, strict mode is automatically enabled, which will return undefined if using this in Global Scope.